# Import Doxygen generated documentation tex in Paper as appendix

Tags: pdfpages, books

I have a paper with the baseclass of `{book}` and I want to include the doxygen generated LaTeX documentation output as an appendix in the paper. I have been using `\includepdf{mydoc.pdf}` although it does not retain the proper page numbers in the table of contents (for obvious reasons).

The generated refman.tex uses a baseclass of `{book}` also. How can I import that as a chapter/appendix or what can I change the base class to so it can be imported that way?

The end result should retain the page numbering for both and formatting for the paper and documentation.

EX

> - Paper
>
>   - TOC
>   - Chap 1
>   - Chap 2
>   - Chap etc
>   - Appendix Documentation
>
>     - TOC
>     - Chap 1
>     - Chap 2
>   - Appendix Other

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349487/controlling-doxygens-latex-output-for-making-pdf-documentation

Comment: Thanks, its kind of a work-around using the PDF. I was hoping to use the raw .tex to generate a completed PDF.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You can highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: could you edit your example to have a complete small document and a small fragment of doxygen generated tex that you want to include. It is very hard to answer as it is unless you have a running doxygen setup.

Comment: Without a MWE, as David says it's pretty tricky to help. As a result, I'm marking as 'unclear'.